# Open Sans and LaTeX Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, fonts

I'm working on a presentation in LaTeX Beamer and would like to use Open Sans Condensed for titles, Open Sans Normal for regular text on the slides and TikZ for graphics.

Is there any way to do so?

This is my draft at the moment:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names, compress]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default, osfigures]{opensans}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{soulutf8}
\setul{1pt}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
        Text 1234567890
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `utf8` rather than `utf8x` as an option for `inputenc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only see the condensed light (cl) series in the opensans sample pdf.  You can set your title font to this using `\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series={\fontseries{cl}}}`